# Can anyone explain me why we use a public folder to hold css and image folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can anyone explain to me why we use a public folder to hold CSS and images folder?I am new to node js and trying to learn in-depth about it.

Comment: We don't: node has no such requirement, because Node is not itself a web server, it is a programming language with a standard library. The choice on what to call your static asset directory depends entirely on your choice of framework (and whether that cares or has some default term it likes to use). For example, Express.js doesn't care, pick whatever you like. Heck, pick more than one dir if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name suggests "public", it is to serve static files (which don't change) like CSS, JavaScript, images, etc.

We keep these files in the public folder and expose the entire folder through proper means.

Now, whoever requests these files (The browser) which are present in this public folder can access the files . Note that you can have any name and expose it , the "public" is just a proper and common name.

Also, by default your folder will not be accessible. You need to enable that.

From express documentation,

```
For example, use the following code to serve images, CSS files, and JavaScript files 
in a directory named public:

app.use(express.static('public'))
Now, you can load the files that are in the public directory:

http://localhost:3000/images/kitten.jpg
http://localhost:3000/css/style.css
http://localhost:3000/js/app.js
http://localhost:3000/images/bg.png
http://localhost:3000/hello.html
```

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html Check this for more info, if you use express.

Lets say you don't keep the files in a folder that is not made public or exposed, what will happen is the browser or any client that tries to retrieve the image or CSS will not be able to access. In this case you need to enable separate routes for these files independently and for all the public files, which is time consuming and complex.

Let me give you an example, consider your webpage has an image of cat in an  tag in html. What browser does is it will make a get request to get that image from the server, if the image is not in the public folder or there is no route setup to handle this file, the browser will not be able to display the image in the webpage.

Note: This is why private pictures are not saved in a public directory, you better have a dynamic route that handles those pictures. Only authenticated users will be able to access. If you place private pictures in public folder, anyone can access it.

Comment: Oh, now I got it. Thanks for your help. Can you please suggest what all things should I focus on when I am trying to learn about node js.

Comment: I got notified that my answer got approved. But, now it's gone. Just to mention that you can approve only one answer. You can upvote multiple answers.

Comment: Anyway, for Node.js, first focus on core Node.js, fs module, http module, streams. Try to get data from 3rd party API and use it. Only when you know core Node.js , move forward to web framework like express.js , socket.io or any other topic.

Comment: Try to create server without extra framework. Understand respnse , request ,etc. These are all streams. Also try to understand event emitter like res.on() . Understand the callback or promise pattern as well.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about it. I am new to StackOverflow. Now I  approved your answer. I will try to learn the things that you said.

Comment: Thanks for the approval. Glad that I could help you. Yeah, learn the topics that I have mentioned. Check Freecodecamp.org later , it is a good one for web development. For core node.js you can use LinkedIn Learning, it gives free for 1 month, I have taken couple of courses there , particularly by Alex Banks, E Henri, Daniel Khan. Great content!

Answer (score 2):

Nodejs is simple a server side scripting language. Its main work is to process data that comes from the client side (i.e HTML) or  frontend and store it to database. After the data from the html are processed then it is needed to be sent back to the browser. On sending data from server to the client , the rendered element need to have different styles and js and image as well. These things are to be made available publicly because the browser should be able to access it and process in client side. so for this and images, css, js and docs as well, we use public fonder.

or putting it simple, those static (constant) files which are accessed by the browser (not server) are kept in the public directory.